# JS not showing text after click twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have this JS Code which is do the Like and Unlike to some article in my website. The problem is when I click Like the Unlike Button shows fine But when I Click Unlike it doesn't show Like again.  It just sticks the Unlike text instead of showing Like after i click Unlike again.  It work again after I refresh the page.

The text is not shown after I click twice but it still executes the SQL method.

**My JS Code**

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.like').click(function(){
        var article = $(this).attr("id");
        var data = 'cid='+article;
        $('.like').html('Unlike');
        $('.like').removeClass('like');
        $('.unlike').addClass('unlike');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/like.php', 
            data: data,
            success: function(result){

            }
        });
    });

    $('.unlike').click(function(){
        var article = $(this).attr("id");
        var data = 'cid='+article;
        $('.unlike').html('Like');
        $('.unlike').removeClass('unlike');
        $('.like').addClass('like');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/like.php', 
            data: data,
            success: function(result){

           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you could also just delegate using .on with a common parent. `$(parent).on('click', '.Like', function() {` and similar for Unlike... however the other solution provided below are probably better :)

Comment: @rlemon Thank You it will be much helpful if you write it as full code, Not for me Just for other users who will look for the same question, i had this solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20936499/2943186) as the best for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event listeners are attached to the elements matching the selector at the time they are bound, changing the class at a later time does not add or remove elements to the event handler.

Create your own toggle functionality instead

```
$(function () {
    $('.like').on('click', function() {
        var flag     = $(this).data('flag'),
            article  = this.id,
            data     = {cid : article};

        $(this).html(flag ? 'Like' : 'Unlike')
               .data('flag', !flag);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/like.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the full code and it's working very fine too

```
$(function () {
    $('.like').on('click', function() {
        var flag     = $(this).data('flag'),
            article  = this.id,
            data     = {cid : article};

        $(this).html(flag ? 'Like' : 'Unlike')
               .data('flag', !flag);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/like.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
              $('.total_likes').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('.removelike').on('click', function() {
        var flag     = $(this).data('flag'),
            article  = this.id,
            data     = {cid : article};

        $(this).html(flag ? 'Unlike' : 'Like')
               .data('flag', !flag);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/like.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
              $('.total_likes').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's Working like a charm BUT there is a problem with Like Button when i click it, it doesn't show Unlike button<br>
But when i click Unlike Button, it show the Like Button Fine<br>
please take a moment and look at it here in video
[Video explain](http://screenr.com/a8TN) 
@adeneo

Comment: @YoussefSubehi -  I probably got the flag part wrong, change it to `$(this).html(flag ? 'Like' : 'Unlike')` to swap them, edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Youssef you may try this

"Like"

```
$(function() {

    $('.like-button').click(function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        if( obj.data('liked') ){
            obj.data('liked', false);
            obj.html('Like');
        }
        else{
            obj.data('liked', true);
            obj.html('Unlike');
        }
    });
});
```

This Code is Work Like Charm
the full Code

```
$(function() {

  $('.like').click(function(){
            article  = this.id,
            data     = {cid : article};
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/like.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
              $('.total_likes').html(result);
            }
        });
      var obj = $(this);
      if( obj.data('liked') ){
          obj.data('liked', false);
          obj.html('Like');
      }
      else{
          obj.data('liked', true);
          obj.html('Unlike');
      }

  });
});


$(function() {

  $('.removelike').click(function(){
            article  = this.id,
            data     = {cid : article};
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/like.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
              $('.total_likes').html(result);
            }
        });
      var obj = $(this);
      if( obj.data('unliked') ){
          obj.data('unliked', false);
          obj.html('UnLike');
      }
      else{
          obj.data('unliked', true);
          obj.html('Like');
      }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to change class and text on ajax callback ! I don't know if it will fix your problem, but at least this must be done this way.

```
    $('.like').click(function(){
        var article = $(this).attr("id");
        var data = 'cid='+article;
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'includes/like.php', 
           data: data,
           success: function(result){
                $('.like').html('Unlike');
                $('.like').removeClass('like');
                $('.unlike').addClass('unlike');
           }
         });
    });


    $('.unlike').click(function(){
        var article = $(this).attr("id");
        var data = 'cid='+article;
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'includes/like.php', 
           data: data,
           success: function(result){
                $('.unlike').html('Like');
                $('.unlike').removeClass('unlike');
                $('.like').addClass('like');
           }
         });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks But i Have Already Try it and it still the same problem with that 
i want to update the text on callback weather it's like or Unlike.